# How to consolidate Hierarchy in a table and loop through it?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Given the following 2 tables:

**GroupsHierarchyTable**

```
AD/Profile Name     Org Level   Org Member
AD_Group1           Region      China
AD_Group1           Region      USA
AD_Group2           Sub Region  China
AD_Group2           Sub Region  Corp
AD_Group3           Sub Region  USA
```

and **OrgTable**

```
Region     Sub Region      Org Code
China      China           m500_ABC
USA        Corp            1098
USA        USA             12345
China      Corp            123_KL
USA        Corp            Z45557
China      Corp            f908L_P
China      China           234G
```

How do I consolidate the Org Members under 1 **AD/Profile Name Org Level** hierarchy?

I currently use the following code to loop through a CSV file to consolidate the Org Codes, but the requirements changed and I'd like to change the program to parse a table instead of the CSV file.

As you can see, `$row.'Org Member' -split '\r?\n'` splits the Org Members because they are separated in the CSV file by a new line. With the new requirement, instead of the Org Members being split by a delimiter (i.e. new line) we replicated the Profile Names and Org Levels on separate rows for more than 1 Org Member belonging to that same hierarchy.

```
Function Query($Query) {
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection 
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$Server;Initial Catalog=$Database;Integrated Security=SSPI" 
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand 
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection 
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $Query 
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter 
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd 
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet 
$a=$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$SqlConnection.Close() 
$DataSet.Tables[0] }
 
$table = Query "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[OrgTable]"
#$table.'Sub Region'.Item(1)
 
$clmns = Import-Csv .\File1.csv
 
$pscoArray = @()
 
foreach ($row in $clmns) {
    $ADGroup = $row.'AD/Profile Name'
    $OrgLevel = $row.'Org Level'
    $data = $table | Where {$_.$OrgLevel -in ($row.'Org Member' -split '\r?\n') }
    $pscoArray += [pscustomobject]@{'AD Group' = $ADGroup; 'Org Codes' = $data.'Org Code' -join '|'}
}
 
Write-SqlTableData -ServerInstance $Server -DatabaseName $Database -InputData $pscoArray -SchemaName "dbo" -TableName "NewTable"
```

***current input:***
CSV file:

```
AD/Profile Name,Org Level,Org Member
AD_Group1,Region,"China
USA"
AD_Group2,Sub Region,"China
Corp"
AD_Group3,Sub Region,USA
```

***Expected Output***:

**NewTable**:

```
AD Group        Org Codes
AD_Group1       M500_ABC|1098|12345|123_KL|Z45557|f908L_P|234G|
AD_Group2       M500_ABC|1098|123_KL|Z45557|f908L_P|234G|
AD_Group3       12345|
```

Comment: You may be able to use `Group-Object` here, which behaves similar to a SQL `GROUP BY`

Comment: @AndrewDavis something like this? `$clmns | Group-Object -Property 'Org Level' | Foreach-Object {
    $_.Name
    $_.Group.'Org Member'
}`

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @HainanZhao I updated the post. please check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually consolidate that logic in one sql query. Change your `SELECT * FROM [dbo].[OrgTable]`
to

```
select g.[AD/Profile Name] as 'AD Group', (
            SELECT distinct o.[Org Code] + '|' 
            From OrgTable o
            JOIN GroupsHierarchyTable g2 
            on g2.[Org Member] = case when g2.[Org Level] = 'Region' then o.Region else o.[Sub Region] end 
            where g2.[AD/Profile Name] = g.[AD/Profile Name]
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ) as 'Org Codes'
from GroupsHierarchyTable g
group by g.[AD/Profile Name]
```

The SQL Result

```
AD Group    Org Codes
AG_Group1   m500_ABC|123_KL|f908L_P|234G|1098|12345|Z45557|
AG_Group2   m500_ABC|234G|1098|123_KL|Z45557|f908L_P|
AG_Group3   12345|
```

Comment: Ohhh that's even better! This way I wont need to run the script on a schedule, i can just create a view :D

Comment: Ok so i created this on my Database, it consolidated great but one minor thing: its creating a | delimiter at the beginning of the Org Codes but doesn't create one at the end. could you switch it around so that | is created at the end? for example, this is what im currently getting: `|m500_ABC|123_KL|f908L_P|234G|1098|12345|Z45557`. it should be `m500_ABC|123_KL|f908L_P|234G|1098|12345|Z45557|`. Notice the starting and ending | delimiter placement

Comment: Ok. Add the '|' after the code. SELECT o.[Org Code] + '|'

Comment: oh one more thing. let's suppose that  AD_Group4 belongs to 2 Org Levels, so say Region and Sub Region. what's currently happening is some of the Org Codes are getting duplicated if they exist in both levels. could you make it so that if the Org Code is already in the delimited list, not to repeat? so that all values in Org Codes are distinct/unique? for example, instead of `Z45557|m500_ABC|123_KL|f908L_P|234G|1098|12345|1098|Z45557|` Notice 1098 and Z45557 values are repeated, it should be: `m500_ABC|123_KL|f908L_P|234G|1098|12345|Z45557|`

Comment: Edited. Added "distinct" in the select query. SELECT distinct o.[Org Code] + '|'